# Why are my real analysis questions on intuition and proof strategy closed?

Tags: discussion, support

I hope I can post here because none of the closers or downvoters left or apprised me of a comment. It doesn't help my future posts and fazes me.  I know they don't have to, but it helps if they can.   Please demystify why my questions are closed and downvoted? Thank you to all.

**put on hold as unclear what you're asking**

**Rectified 1.** https://math.stackexchange.com/q/696131/85079

[If f' exists and f'(c) > 0 then f'(x) > 0 for all |x - c| < d for some d. (S.A. pp 137 question 5.2.8b)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/692350/85079),
    https://math.stackexchange.com/q/678715/85079,
**Revised** https://math.stackexchange.com/q/679700/85079

> I don't understand "unclear." I wrote my essays, thoughts and work. I numbered my questions. Yes, I know some questions are long. But I put them in gray boxes like this to clarify.

**This question is missing context or other details**

**Revised** https://math.stackexchange.com/q/690129/85079

> What is missing? Again I wrote my essays, thoughts and work and numbered.

Comment: I wasn't involved in any of the closings, so I can only guess. I find your style of posting a bit annoying. Bulk of the post consists of scanned images from textbooks - a practice that many of us associate with laziness. Then you shoot several questions in rapid-fire mode. The questions themselves appear to be fragments rather than full sentences - another sign of laziness. Then I need to refer to a dictionary to understand the meaning of the words in 2/3 fragments. At that point all thoughts about trying to figure out which step exactly you had problems with have long gone.

Comment: Visually the posts seem sort of busy and erratic -- I've peeked at a couple of them, and since and I've felt like it takes a lot of work to figure out how to actually read your question. Since I'm lazy, I haven't really gotten very far into any of them. I haven't cast any vote on anything in any direction; although if my first impressions were that the post seemed to be in bad faith, I would have also considered voting to close with "unclear what you're asking" as the reason.

Comment: The questions are drawn out and noisy. Distill your question into something more succinct.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Please tell me which word fazed you? I'll revise. English is not my first language. I'm not fantastic with latex, ergo images prevent errors. And they help to separate what is from a book and mine? Is this loathsome?

Comment: @copper.hat what does noisy mean here? And what needs distillaton?

Comment: Nobody uses words like "presage" or "vatic" except avid Scrabble players.

Answer (score 13):

When I look at the linked-to questions, they do not invite me to answer them.  There are:

$\bullet$ Unexplained abbreviations (What is S.A.?)

$\bullet$ Visually complicated formatting: e.g. lines of text which are underlined and/or numbered, in several colors.  I can pass my eyes over these complicated images several times and still not be sure (i) what you are saying, (ii) what you are quoting from, and (iii) exactly what your questions are.

$\bullet$ An annoying and distracting use of obscure words in inappropriate contexts: e.g. "presage", "vatic", "emanate feyly".

I am a native English speaker and a child of two English professors, but I had to look up "vatic" and I still have no idea what "emanate feyly" means.  I do know what "presage" means and that it is not being used properly here.  When you (mis)use obscure words like this, you create the impression that you would rather show off / play your own verbal games than communicate in a way which makes things easier for the reader.  It is only natural then that the reaction to your questions is negative.

You say that you are not a native English speaker.  Fine: then keep your English especially simple.  Unless your native language is "stilted English", there is no reasonable explanation for your word choices.  You need to decide whether you want to play word games or get your math questions answered: it seems that you are having trouble playing it both ways.

**Added**: Okay, I was playing just a little bit dumb: I do know that S.A. means "Stephen Abbott", but only because it is listed in the OP's profile.  (This is not the right place for this information, and also including the author's initials is not a sufficient reference for the text.  Many questions are attributed to multiple texts, which honestly does seem confusing to me.)  I gather that "emanate feyly" is supposed to mean something like "appear as if by magic".  When this is used in response to things written in standard texts, I find it very annoying.  The implication is that the texts are very badly written and that no ordinary mortal could understand or follow them.  I disagree with that: the quoted texts are very well written.  The OP's tone thus creates the impression that it is someone else's responsibility to "demystify" (a direct quote!) these standard math texts.  I strenuously disagree that such demystification is our job.

Comment: Alright, English dude, what about 'advisor' vs. 'adviser'?

Comment: @Will: see http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/advisor.

Comment: thank you. i try to revise this.

Comment: Most amazingly, googling "emanate feyly" gives [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695175/prove-limit-of-modulus-of-quotient-of-two-functions-is-infinity-s-a-pp-144-que) as a first result.

Comment: @Pedro: Don't get excited. Google personalizes the results based on your online activity. Try searching from a whole other computer that you've never used before, without logging in to your Google account, and the results may differ. You might want to try searching using DuckDuckGo to see how a slightly more objective search results query looks like. (What *is* amazing is that searching the phrase on DDG, with quotation marks, returns only a single result. The aforementioned thread.)